# Forwarding email via VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I intend to forward emails to certain individuals (To & CC). The addresses are attached with email as CSV file.

The code is giving

> runtime error -2147024809 (80070057)

Error is showing on this line

```
objForwardMail.SendUsingAccount = objMailAccount
```

```
Sub Forwardemailstointendedrecepients(objMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objForwardMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objAddRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    '    Dim objMailAccounts As Outlook.Accounts
    Dim objMailAccount As Outlook.Account
    
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Dim xlFileName As String
    Dim MainRecipient As String
    Dim OtherRecipients As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    
    FilePath = "C:\Users\BSERVER\Desktop\Email_CSV_Path\"
    
    For Each Atmt In objMail.Attachments
        If Atmt.FileName = "Email_Addresses.csv" Then
            xlFileName = FilePath & Atmt.FileName
                  
            Atmt.SaveAsFile xlFileName
                
            Set xlWB = workbooks.Open(xlFileName)
                
            MainRecipient = Range("D2").Value
            OtherRecipients = Range("E2").Value
            workbooks.Close
                
            Set objForwardMail = objMail.Forward
            Set objRecipient = objForwardMail.Recipients.Add(MainRecipient)
            objRecipient.Type = olTo
            objForwardMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
            Set objAddRecipient = objForwardMail.Recipients.Add(OtherRecipients)
            objAddRecipient.Type = olCC
            objForwardMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
            objForwardMail.SendUsingAccount = objMailAccount
            objForwardMail.Send            
        End If
    Next Atmt
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you show the line where the error happens and the complete error message, noone knows all runtime errors by heart. That said: Outlook does not have a  `Workbooks`-object. If you want to open the file in Excel, you first need to open Excel. Your variable `xlApp` was probably ment for that, but you're not using it. And I wonder why you declared it as `Object` and not as `Excel.Application` when you're using early binding anyhow.

Comment: Error is showing on this line `objForwardMail.SendUsingAccount = objMailAccount`

Comment: According to the definition of `objMailAccount`, it is an object, therefore you need to use `Set` in that statement. But have you assinged something to it?

Comment: When I am assigning to this object using set command like this `Set objMailAccount = Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts` it gives me type mismatch error.

Comment: Because `Accounts` is a collection, isn't it?

Comment: You may be right. So what will be the solution Sir?

Comment: Appears you do not have a need for `.SendUsingAccount`. Delete `objForwardMail.SendUsingAccount = objMailAccount` to send "normally".

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `Account` object instance in the code before using it:

```
objForwardMail.SendUsingAccount = objMailAccount
```

The [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. For example:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
  If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
   Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
   Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
   Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
   oMail.Send 
  End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```